# How to enable file change notification for network drives?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, filesystems, network-shares, notifications

When you run any program handling local drive, when you externally change file the program usually detects such change and offers to reload it.

When the file is located on network no such thing happen leading to many problems with common software, for example:

- Visual Studio sees the old copy in editor
- Free Commander **moves** file from one drive to other, yet the source file is still listed (sic! -- more like a bug in FC, but problematic nevertheless)

I would like to solve this once for good -- so how to tell Windows to enable file change notification for given drive?

*In my case it is actually a local drive but simply "routed" through shared folder in VirtualBox.*

Comment: you cannot, unless the program you are using was specially crafted to do so. Windows does not treat network drives the same as it does physical volumes, so the program will generally not be accessing the actual file, except when opening and saving.

Comment: @FrankThomas, thank you, please post your comment as answer so I could accept it.